# Is it permissible to look at human heart, liver, and other internal organs? Are internal organs awrah and impermissible to look or Imagine?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sin

Is it permissible to look at human heart, liver, and other internal organs? Are internal organs awrah and impermissible to look or Imagine ?

Comment: Please elaborate why its impermissible in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Asalamoualaikum,

I do believe that looking at the internal organs of a human, any other animal or living/non-living being is permissible for medical or educational purposes as this allows us to have a better understanding of the human anatomy. However it is best to use an animal as a muslim after death should really be buried. But I'm not a scholar.

As far as the **study** of the awrah, it is permissible as long as it is not for sexual desires or arousal. Imagining them only becomes haram when it passes the line and becomes for sexual intent.

Hope this helps. :)